# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message

Tags: php

I'm trying to do an exception to check conection to a DataBase, but i keep getting this:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can't 
Connect to DB' in C:\wamp64\www\Avanzado\MIUII\Login\conect.php on line 19
( ! ) Exception: Can't Connect to DB in 
C:\wamp64\www\Avanzado\MIUII\Login\conect.php on line 19
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  244256  {main}( )   ...\login.php:0
2   0.0011  249256  include( 'C:\wamp64\www\Avanzado\MIUII\Login\conect.php' 
)   ...\login.php:13
```

My code for this page so far:

```
<?php

$conexion=@mysql_connect("localhosta", "root", "");
$dbseleccionada=@mysql_select_db("login", $conexion);

if (!$conexion) 
{
throw new Exception ('No se pudo establecer una conexion');
}
```

Comment: what's the php version?

Comment: `localhosta` that's a typo, btw. it should be `localhost`.

Comment: 5.6.25... And yes, but i'm forcing the error for test

Comment: *"but i'm forcing the error for test"* - Oh, so the plot thickens then. You should have included that in the question, rather than me/others finding about what the real question is "after the fact" and in comments.

Answer (score 1):

When you throw an Exception, it has to be handled, so you should put it inside `try` like this:

```
<?php

$conexion=@mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$dbseleccionada=@mysql_select_db("login", $conexion);

if (!$conexion) 
{
    try{
        throw new Exception ('No se pudo establecer una conexion');
    } catch (Exception $e){
        // Enter whatever you want
    }
}
```

But instead of throwing an Exception, you should probably just write a message or alert, that the connection was not possible.

Comment: Tried this... Get the message, but need to put an echo and an a $e->getmessage
And I must do and exeption, it's kind of an exam :/

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. This is how you handle an Exception... with a try catch block... @GastonFlores if you need to get the message then do exactly what you are saying... `echo $e->getMessage();`. Now why you would want to do this in the first place instead of just echoing is beyond me.